# Read only a section within a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to exclude particular content from my file. For example
My sample code:

```
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
[EmployeeID] INT NULL,
[Name] VARCHAR (50) NULL
);


GO
CREATE TABLE #tempAP_Data_new       (                                                                
planeID INT ,
 APNM   INT,
)

DECLARE             
 @APNM  [VARCHAR] (100) ,   
 @MajorModel [VARCHAR] (100) ,  
 @MinorModel [VARCHAR] (100) ,

CREATE TABLE  #tempnew_Data(                                                                 
planeNum INT ,
APNMID INT,
)
GO
```

In this I need only the `CREATE TABLE` Statement till go and not the `CREATE TABLE #`. The output should be :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
[EmployeeID] INT NULL,
[Name] VARCHAR(50)NULL
);
```

My code was:

```
$searchCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE" 
$alterTable = (Get-Content $path\$deltaFile -Delimiter 'GO') -match  "(?m)^$searchCreateTable*"
```

Answer (score 2):

If the statement is always within the first 5 lines, you can use the `-Head` parameter:

```
Get-Content $path\$deltaFile -Head 5
```

Otherwise you can split the file:

```
(Get-Content $path\$deltaFile -raw) -split 'Go' | select -Index 1
```

Comment: The create statement won't always come in the exact position. Its actually a delta file

Comment: This logic won't actually work as it cannot be always in index 2